# Python win32com: set email header

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I have an issue to write in an email header in python using library win32com.
But I'm not sure if it is possible.

We can read an email header using:

```
import win32com.client
outlook =win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
mess=message.Body
internet_header = message.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F")
print(internet_header)
```

But I don't know if we can set the email header using something similar. 
it is not working using something like that:

```
new_mail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F", internet_header)
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Are you setting  PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS on the received messages? Why? Or are you trying to set a MIME header on an outgoing message?

Comment: I need to send the email Azure Information Protection Classifications which is stored in the email header. In C# the equivalent will be using the method SetExtendedProperty().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a MIME header on an outgoing email, set a named property in the PS_INTERNET_HEADERS namespace:

```
 message.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/X-My-Header", "some value")
```